# Simple augmented reality API for Android

Tags: android, geolocation, augmented-reality

I want to make a simple location based app for android. What are my (free) options. I looked at SDKs like Wikitude and Vuforia, but they are too much for my needs. I do not need image recognition and stuff... I just need to see on camera direction and distance to some coordinate - location.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**Junaio**](http://www.junaio.com/) and **[Metaio](http://www.metaio.com/)** augmented reality frameworks. They are easy to work with. And also take a look at this [Augmented Reality Framework comaprison table](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks). You can choose GPS feature enabled Frameworks from it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use api's called Junaio or Metaio. Before somedays I have just worked with it. It is very nice to work with and results are also very good with nice efficiency. Just try with it. Here is the [link](https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/location-based-ar/).